# How to create simple animations in 3gp format?

Tags: animation, 3gp

I am trying to create a simple animation which includes face of a famous character. For example Santa Clause. The face and the lips of the character will act according to the given input message. For example if a string is inputed then the lips of the character will be opened and closed till the end of the string while the given input message is vocalized using a text to speech converter. Moreover if the " :) " is used the character in the animation will smile. How could I do this? I was told that I can create this type of animations using "smill". But this is not convenient for the other purposes therefore I need to use a different method. Could you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure about if you need only to convert an avi or the like video file to 3gp format, or wish something that involves quite more. If it is the first case, you can try the following free converter :

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/3GP_Converter